# Give applications of $\beth_3$ other than $\beth_3=\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})))$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

What are a few applications of $\beth_3$ other than $\beth_3=\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})))$ or any other variations of generalized identities that can easily be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number)? This is not a homework problem; I am merely studying independently.

---

To explain what I mean by “applications,” here is an application of each beth number before $\beth_3$ other than the power set definition:

- $\beth_0=\aleph_0$ is the basis of the beth numbers, and $\beth_0$ equals the cardinality of the natural numbers and also equals the cardinality of the integers. For concreteness, you could say that a series sums together this many terms.
- $\beth_1$ is the cardinality of the real numbers or any interval subset of the real line. You could loosely say that an integral adds together this many terms.
- While there are infinitely many functions that take a subset of the real line and return a subset of the real line (denoted $\mathbb{R^R}$), the number of them is defined an equals $\beth_2$.

Comment: It's not true that $\beth_1$ is the cardinality of any subset of the real line - It's an upper bound for the cardinality of any subset of the real line. There are always finite/countable subsets of the real line and - should $\operatorname{CH}$ fail - there may be many more cardinalities which are realized by sets of real numbers.

Comment: @StefanMesken Ah, you are absolutely right. What I meant to communicate was that a continuous interval like $(0,1]$ or $[-4,2]$ has cardinality $\beth_1$. I hadn't stopped and realized that $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{R}$. Thank you for catching that error!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not an interesting application. According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/65742/1039170), the number of topologies (or nonhomeomorphic topologies) over an infinite set $X$ is $2^{2^{|X|}}$. So the number of topologies (or nonhomeomorphic topologies) over $\mathbb{R}^k$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $\mathbb{C}_p$, $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, $\ell_p$ with $1\le p\le\infty$, set of measurable functions over $E$ (a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of positive measure), $L^p(E)$ for measurable $E$ with $1\le p\le\infty$, $C^k(\Omega)$ with open $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ and $0\le k\le\infty$, set of holomorphic functions over an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, ... is $\beth_3$.