# What can be said about the number of topologies on an infinite set?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I read somewhere that for $\mathbb{R}$, the number of topologies is indeed the same as the obvious upper bound, namely $2^{2^{|\mathbb{R}|}}$. Does the same hold for all infinite sets $X$, i.e. is the cardinality of the set of topologies on $X$ equal to $2^{2^{|X|}}$? How would one prove it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cardinality of the set of all topologies on $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65731/what-is-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-topologies-on-mathbbr) (The accepted answer seems to be what you are after.)