# The cardinality of the set of topologies over $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be the set of all possible topologies over the set of positive integers. We can easily show that there is injection from $\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})$ to $S$, and one  from $S$ to $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathbb{N}))$, because of the Continum Hypothesis we are sure that there is bijection between $S$ and one of the sets $\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})$ Or $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathbb{N}))$ , so which set is, and can we define this bijective map.
In other words what is the cardinality of $S$?

Comment: The Continuum Hypothesis, even if you assume it is true, tells you nothing about cardinalities between $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|$ and $|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))|$; in particular, it does not imply that there are no cardinalities strictly between these two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cardinality of the set of all topologies on $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65731/what-is-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-topologies-on-mathbbr) (The question is about $\Bbb R$ but the answers are about any infinite set.)