# Can the number of topologies on a set $X$ be equal to $2^{2^{|X|}}$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Is there a non empty set $X$ such that $|T_X| = 2^{2^{|X|}}$ where $T_X$ are all topologies on $X$?

I know $T_X$ to be a strict subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ and that no finite set works.

Comment: The empty set does not work. The only topology on the empty set is $\{\varnothing\}$. But $P(\varnothing)=\{\varnothing\}$, and $P(P(\varnothing))=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$, so there is no bijection.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65731/what-is-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-topologies-on-mathbbr

Comment: The answer in the question linked-to by Jakobian answers your question: any infinite set.