# Can a Set Have Infinitely-Many Non-Homeomorphic Topologies?

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a set. Is it possible for X to have an infinite number of topologies up to homeomorphism (i.e. infinitely-many different topological structures)?

Comment: Every manifold of dimension $\ge 1$ has the same cardinality as the real numbers. So that is a whole lot of different topologies right there.

Comment: In fact a set of infinite cardinality $\kappa$ has $2^{2^\kappa}$  non-homeomorphic topologies: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65731/what-is-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-topologies-on-mathbbr

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there uncountably many non homeomorphic ways to topologize a countably infinite set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34838/are-there-uncountably-many-non-homeomorphic-ways-to-topologize-a-countably-infin)

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  Take for example the real line plus some finite number of isolated points.  You can change the topology so that any number of the points are isolated and still have uncountably many left over, and no two of these topologies are homeomorphic.

Comment: the question is for non-homeomorphic topologies

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko Whoops, you are correct, edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  For example, we can take $\Bbb N$ under the topologies defined as follows:
$$
\tau_0 = \{\emptyset,\Bbb N\}\\
\tau_1 = \tau_0 \cup \{1\} \cup (\Bbb N \setminus \{1\})\\
\vdots\\
\tau_n = \{\emptyset,\Bbb N\} \cup\mathcal P(\{1,\dots,n\}) \cup \{(\Bbb N \setminus S): S \in \mathcal P(\{1,\dots,n\})\}
$$
each of these topologies consist of different finite numbers of open sets, so no two are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal S=\{X\subseteq\mathbb R:|X|=\mathfrak c\}$ where $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$. For each $X\in\mathcal S$, there are only $\mathfrak c$ continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb R$ (since such a function is determined by its restriction to a countable dense subset of $X$); hence $|\{Y\in\mathcal S:Y\text{ is homeomorphic to }X\}|\le\mathfrak c$. Since $|\mathcal S|=2^\mathfrak c$, it follows that there are $2^\mathfrak c$ non-homeomorphic sets in $\mathcal S$; in other words, $\mathbb R$ has $2^\mathfrak c$ non-homeomorphic subspaces of cardinality $\mathfrak c$. Since each of those subspaces is homeomorphic to a topology on $\mathbb R$, there are $2^\mathfrak c$ non-homeomorphic separable metrizable topologies on $\mathbb R$.